# Trying to build an Applicative instance that handles monetary amounts in different currencies, am I on the wrong track?

Tags: haskell

I'm giving yet another go at Haskell (reading the awesome [learnyouahaskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) tutorial) and I'm desperately looking for a nail to apply this magnificient hammer to.

My day job is in E-Commerce, and we have tons of software design issues manipulating prices. So I figured, it could be nice to use the Haskell type system to abstract away things like converting between currencies or pre-tax / after-tax prices while guaranteeing correctness.

Here is a rough idea of what I'm trying to achieve (obviously not-compiling, wouldn't be here otherwise):

```
data Money a = Amount String a | ConversionError
    deriving Show

convert :: String -> Money Double -> Money Double
convert toCurrency (Amount fromCurrency 0) = Amount toCurrency 0
convert "EUR" (Amount "USD" x) = Amount "EUR" (0.92 * x)
convert "USD" (Amount "EUR" x) = Amount "USD" (1.09 * x)
convert _ _ = ConversionError

instance Functor Money where
    fmap f (Amount currency number) = Amount currency (f number)

instance Applicative Money where
    ConversionError <*> _ = ConversionError
    Amount x f <*> amount = let Amount _ n = convert x amount
                            in
                                Amount x (f n)
    pure = Amount "EUR"

eur5 = Amount "EUR" 5
usd5 = Amount "USD" 5


main = do
    print $ fmap (+1) eur5 -- Amount "EUR" 6
    print $ convert "EUR" usd5 -- Amount "EUR" 4.6000000000000005
    print $ (+) <$> eur5 <*> usd5 -- I'd like it to print: Amount "EUR" 9.58
```

This doesn't compile because:

```
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Double’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for
        (<*>) :: Money (a -> b) -> Money a -> Money b
      at src/Main.hs:14:21
Expected type: Money Double
  Actual type: Money a
```

And I understand why.

I think a possible fix would be to let the Money type carry the conversion function, but it makes the whole thing less elegant, I'd have to declare my prices like this:

```
data Money a = Amount (String -> (Money a) -> (Money a)) a
eur5 = Amount convert "EUR" 5
```

What I'd really like is if I could start worrying about conversions only when computations happen and not need to embed the conversion function inside the `Money` values.

So, am I on the right track but mis-understanding something, or is Applicative really not a solution to simplify this sort of problem?

Comment: Money doesn't look like a functor at all, much less an applicative. Does it make a sense to talk about `Money String` or `Money ()` or `Money (Int, [Double->IO()])`?

Comment: @n.m. I would agree. Yet, it might just be that `Money` is simply a bad term for the idea. It seems that a `Money a` is just a value of type `a` decorated with a message "note that prices are in currency C" -- with a `Maybe` on top to handle failure. Also, the currency is set and tested at run-time (which could be good or bad depending on the actual aim...)

Comment: @n.m. thanks, really convincing when you put it this way :)

Comment: I would not recommend learnyouahaskell for haskell learning. unless you really like comics but in that area, there are also some better ones, like Tintin

Comment: @nicolas what would you recommend for learning haskell? The comics on learnyouahaskell don't bother me, I find they make the pages more appealing and less frightening. Form aside, do you object to the content on this website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is Applicative really not a solution to simplify this sort of problem?

Yes, it isn't. As you already said, the problem is that

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

needs to work with any `a` and `b`, but you allow only `a ~ Double`, `b ~ Double`.

However, if we think of any `Applicative f` as a container that knows how to apply functions, it seems rather weird to store some kind of `Money` in there. Also, it seems like you only want the `Applicative` instance for `(+) <$> a <*> b`, which is a misuse. Instead, write a small little helper:

```
($+) :: Money a -> Money a -> Money a
(Amount c a) $+ (Amount c' b) = ...
```

This also gives you a lot more power for later changes. For example, you could use a phantom type instead of your current approach to tag the Money with the currency:

```
newtype Money c a = Amount a deriving Show

data USD
data EUR

usd :: Num a => a -> Money USD a
usd = Amount

eur :: Num a => a -> Money EUR a
eur = Amount

($+) :: Money c a -> Money c a -> Money c a
(Amount a) $+ (Amount b) = Amount $ a + b

-- eur 5 $+ usd 4 = type error
```

However, keep in mind that currency is a rather bad type for compile-time conversion, since the rates change all the time. A more realistic approach would be

```
($+) :: Fractional a => CurrencyEnv -> Money a -> Money a -> Maybe (Money a)
```

where you load the `CurrencyEnv` at the beginning of your program. Keep in mind that you shouldn't use `Double` for currency related tasks, unless you want to explain your boss why you're missing some pennies. `Data.Ratio.Rational` is better suited.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is called a "[unit of measure](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/akenn/units/CEFP09TypesForUnitsOfMeasure.pdf)", which is a type quotient by some algebraic theory to unify say, dollar.eur^2 with eur.dollar.eur

Zeta's solution uses [phantom types](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/publications/With.pdf) to ensure "from inside" some consistency while letting people use your types "from outside"

It's a first step, but the equational part would be missing which can be a problem or not.

I think one would need a ring solver (isn't it the term ?) to handle the equivalence between exponents of your types.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally edited instead of comment: Use `&times;` instead of `*`, or use `\*` to make sure that the asterisk doesn't get interpreted as markdown.